# Get the value from selected rows of recyclerView (java)

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, multipleselection

Well I have a RecyclerView  and I am selecting multiple values from that and want to append the value of selected rows into an array but I don't know what am doing wrong its returning null : my `adpater`

```
import com.bignerdranch.android.multiselector.MultiSelector;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by MACBOOK on 07/03/16.
 */


public class ChannelsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChannelsAdapter.ChannelsViewHolder> implements Filterable  {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;

    List<ChannelsInformation> data = Collections.emptyList();

    private final List<ChannelsInformation> filteredChannelsList;

    private final MultiSelector mMultiSelector = new MultiSelector();

      ArrayList <String> selected;



    public ChannelsAdapter(Context context,  List<ChannelsInformation> data){

        inflater =  LayoutInflater.from(context);


        this.context = context;


        this.data = data;


        filteredChannelsList = data;
    }

    public void remove(int position){
        data.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }


    @Override
    public ChannelsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_channel_row, parent, false);

        ChannelsViewHolder holder = new ChannelsViewHolder(rowView);

        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ChannelsViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        ChannelsInformation current = data.get(position);

        holder.CHANNELNAME.setText(current.channelName);
        holder.ID.setText(current.id);
        holder.mSolvedCheckBox.setChecked(current.isSelected);






    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new UserFilter(this ,filteredChannelsList);
    }

private static class UserFilter extends Filter {

    private final ChannelsAdapter adapter;

    private final List<ChannelsInformation> originalList;

    private final List<ChannelsInformation> filteredList;

    private UserFilter(ChannelsAdapter adapter, List<ChannelsInformation> originalList) {
        super();
        this.adapter = adapter;
        this.originalList = new ArrayList<>(originalList);
        this.filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        filteredList.clear();
        final FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

        if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
            filteredList.addAll(originalList);



        } else {
            final String filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();


            for (final ChannelsInformation channel : originalList) {






            }
        }
        results.values = filteredList;
        results.count = filteredList.size();
        return results;
    }


    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        adapter.filteredChannelsList.clear();
        if  ((ArrayList<ChannelsInformation>) results.values != null ) {

            adapter.filteredChannelsList.addAll((ArrayList<ChannelsInformation>) results.values);
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    } }






class ChannelsViewHolder extends SwappingHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    TextView CHANNELNAME,ID;
    CheckBox mSolvedCheckBox;




    public ChannelsViewHolder(View itemView) {


        super(itemView , mMultiSelector);

        mMultiSelector.setSelectable(true);

        mSolvedCheckBox = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.selectedChannelCheckBox);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        CHANNELNAME = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ChannelNameTxtView);
        ID = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ChannelRowIdTextView);





    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (!mMultiSelector.tapSelection(this)) {
            Toast.makeText(context,CHANNELNAME.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            mSolvedCheckBox.toggle();


          selected.add(ID.toString());


            Log.d(""+selected , " : value of selected ");


        }




    }
}}
```

another class :

```
public class ChannelsInformation {
    String id,channelName;
    boolean isSelected;
}
```

on myFragmentCLass :

```
Fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        String data = "";
        List<ChannelsInformation> stList = ((ChannelsAdapter) channelsAdapter).data;

        for (int i = 0; i < stList.size(); i++) {
            ChannelsInformation singleStudent = stList.get(i);
            if (singleStudent.isSelected) {

                data = data + "\n" + singleStudent.channelName;

            }

        }

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
            "Selected Students: \n" + data, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();




    }
});
```

Well am trying this from past 4 hours , you can see that  I even tried `multiselector` its an library for created an `selectMode`  as same what we have on listView  , now I putted an checkBox in my View and trying to get theValue of checkBox of the checkBox if its checked then show the data but  am getting `null` in return  , if anybody's knows wrong here then please point it out it'll me so helpful for me and appreciated by me , thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to create `List<YourItem> selectedItems`
and add even selected item. Don't forget remove unselected item from this list. Create getter in this adapter

```
public List<YoutItem> getSelectedItens(){

 return selectedItems;
}
```

[it's](https://github.com/jamesvanhallen/MyExpandableRecyclerView/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/futureinapps/myexpandablerecyclerview/SimpleAdapter.java) example with map

Comment: @llya thanks a lot for responding man , basically am an iOS developer and am not too much into android ye so still figuring out all this aspects , so can you please explain me a little bit  in deep ? please because i didnt get the exact point from your question

Comment: hey @llya thanks for your link , so after seeing your example what i need is in  `onBindViewHolder` , am i right  ?

Comment: hey @llya  can you take a look am getting a null exception here `            public void onClick(View view) {
               if (!selected.contains(current.channelName)) {
                    holder.mSolvedCheckBox.setChecked(true);
                    selected.add(current.channelName);
                    map.put(current.channelName, true);

                    
               } else {
                    holder.mSolvedCheckBox.setChecked(false);

                    map.remove(current);


                }

            }` can you tell me whats wrong here ?

Comment: hey man thanks for the example that was the push , :) its working fine now

Answer (score 1):

Well I don't see your initialization of

```
ArrayList<String> selected;
```

Do so

```
public ChannelsAdapter(Context context, List<ChannelsInformation> data) {

    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    this.context = context;

    this.data = data;

    filteredChannelsList = data;

    // like this
    selected = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Comment: hey @mithun thanks a lot for answering man , i really appreciate this , but in code am not adding them yet into any array am just iterating through all the data and checking if the view is selected to not  `            for (int i = 0; i < stList.size(); i++) {
                ChannelsInformation singleStudent = stList.get(i);
                if (singleStudent.isSelected) {

                    data = data + "\n" + singleStudent.channelName;

                }` see